# Find connecting areas with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Perhaps it's a very newbie question but I have images from a room like this

[image: room example image with a green wall and grey border]

where I am interested in the grey border at the bottom of every wall. As I know the dimensions of this, I can estimate the distance to it. However, I am not yet successful in correctly extracting this through opencv. As I can make two masks, one for the green wall and one for the grey border, they can also be added to each other. But is there any way to define that they have to *connect*? As that makes the script much more robust instead of something like this draft where it simply follows the two masks, without any 'connection' rules

[image: draft of a bitwise mask]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A better way would be to try & detect lines using [Canny edge detection](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) and/or [Hough lines](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).